# Selenium v2: use current browser session

Tags: php, python, selenium

How can I reuse current browser window and session?

Authorization is made by smart-card with certificate, so I can't use blank browser to test the application.

I saw previous similar questions here, but v2 has released.

Comment: You want to attach to a browser window that was not started by webdriver? If you explain the authorization process a bit more I might be able to help you use webdriver to do it.

Comment: It's not possible to attach driver to current browser session, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: @aychedee, it uses ssl layer of https to authorize. Using USB e-token.

Comment: @Andrey-Botalov I saw it, but it's for v1.

Comment: @DmitryR It's for v2 (`Component-WebDriver`)

Comment: I don't understand why this would prevent you from using webdriver to do the authorization. Almost any user interaction with the browser can be done. You would just need to have the USB e-token plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium Webdriver protocol allows uploading a Firefox profile that should be used for the test session. You need to send a zipped and base64-encoded profile data folder to Selenium. [Here's some information on how to achieve this using the Facebook php-webdriver.](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Launching-Browsers#firefox)

This could be a way to use some special preparation for your test browser.

If you need certain certificates to be installed: these are part of the user profile [in a file called cert8.db.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files) If you've created a user profile that has the certificates installed, you can follow the above guide to use it for your Selenium tests.

Comment: Thanks. I think this method will work, but it's not suitable for testing software in the company.

Comment: How so? Are you using different browsers?

Comment: I'm using FF with installed certificates. Blank profile will not work.

Comment: The whole point here is that you won't be using a blank profile, You can set up a special "Testing" profile with your certificates, and use it only for selenium testing.